# Throw to 404 error page if a bad route is found?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I use ASP.Net URL Routing for SEO and when I run into a routename that is bad in (i.e. /Games/{RouteName}) I want to pass it to my 404 page for handeling. I check  the DB to make sure {RouteName} is a valid name for a game. If the RouteName is valid I want to continue processing as normal but if the DB comes back and does not find a corisponding RouteName I would like to some how have the server act as if a truly bad URL was entered. How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a bit of messing around in IIS I have figure this out. As endyourif suggested I need to throw a 404 resposne in my code behind, which was done by Response.StatusCode = 404; I also had to configure IIS's Error Pages for the 404 to point to my 404.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest throwing a 404 error inside your logic that determines it is not valid, e.g.

```
if (!<validRouteName>) {
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "Game not found.");
}
```

Comment: HttpStatusCodeResult is an MVC code the only equivalent I could think of for this is Response.StatusCode = 404. This partialy works, it does cause a 404 but it is being handeled by the default IIS 404 and not my custom 404. Is there a way to get my custom 404 page to handle it? I have a code block in my Global.asax files that is supposed to capture 404s and pass it to my custom 404

Comment: protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exception is HttpException)
        {
            if (((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Server.ClearError();
                Server.Transfer("~/404.aspx", false);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Rather than Response.StatusCode can you throw an HttpException?  As it appears that is what your code is expecting -- OR -- you could update your code to check the response.statuscode as well.